Why is the button selection initialized when Stringvar() is initialized?
enter image description here
The title is all my question
Looking at the code, Stringvar() looks like a variable that temporarily stores the value of the button when the button is selected.
So why is the button selection reset even though I reset Stringvar()?

Please don’t post pictures of code. Take the time to copy and paste the code, and give it appropriate markup so that we can read it.

The button selection and the value of the StringVar are intrinsically tied together. If you change one, the other automatically changes. That is how they are designed to work.
